Necessity Of Reiterated Line In Proof For Material Implication
As far as I can tell, the following proof of material implication is valid. However, I am concerned by the apparent necessity of reiterating line 9 at line 11. Does that render the proof invalid, or does it (as I suspect) simply indicate that a more efficient proof exists? Left margin numbers indicate dependency.


Without reiteration here it could be said to be unnatural in terms of natural sequence...

That's my impression too. But does the reiteration indicate that a more efficient proof is available?

The proof is correct. Reiteration is a primitive rule in Fitch style natural deduction systems for classical logic. It is based on the reflexivity of the logical consequence relation, i.e. the fact that any proposition entails itself. Whether this is the simplest way to formulate a proof depends on what rules your system of deduction provides. Given standard Fitch rules, it looks simple enough. An alternative would be to assume ¬(P → Q), derive P ∧ ¬Q then derive by de Morgan ¬(¬P ∨ Q) to get a contradiction. Probably about the same length.

Good to know the proof is valid, thanks. I found it surprisingly difficult, given the simplicity of the sequent!

It's a correct use of the rule so the proof is correct.
It can be simplified a bit though, depending on what exactly your set of rules look like.
In the first subproof, rather than assuming ~Q first you can derive Q from the contradiction with P and ~P directly. The rule of absurdity states that any formula may derived from a contradiction.
In the second subproof, it is usually allowed to use implication introduction directly once the succedent Q has been established, even when the antecedent P is not present as an assumption in the proof. If we know Q then we can be sure to also have P -> Q for any P, even when we didn't need P to arrive at Q.
So you could drop lines 4, 6, 10, 11. But again, it depends on how the rules in your textbook are formulated exactly, and in any event there is nothing wrong about your proof.
